# Does Lwt utilise data dependencies to increase paralleism

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I'm trying to work out what specifically lwt is doing in a couple of examples:

If I have:

```
let%lwt x = f () in
let%lwt y = g () in
return ()
```

Does this run f then g, or since y doesn't rely on x will it run both in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, no, because you are using `Lwt.t` as monad, rather than as an applicative.

## Monads

You're probably already familiar with asynchronous IO and the functions `Lwt.bind : 'a Lwt.t -> ('a -> 'b Lwt.t) -> 'b Lwt.t` and `Lwt.return : 'a -> 'a Lwt.t`. Just in case, though, I will give a brief recap:

- `Lwt.bind promise callback` awaits `promise`, and upon resolution, calls `callback` with the result, getting back another promise.
- `Lwt.return data` creates a promise that resolves to `data`.

A monad is a generic type `'a t` that has some function `bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t` and some function `return : 'a -> 'a t`. (These functions must also follow certain laws, but I digress.) Obviously, the type `'a Lwt.t` with the functions `Lwt.bind` and `Lwt.return` form a monad.

Monads are a common functional programming pattern when one wants to represent some kind of "effect" or "computation," in this case asynchronous IO. Monads are powerful because the `bind` function lets later computations depend on the results of earlier ones. If `m : 'a t` represents some computation that results in `'a`, and `f : 'a -> 'b t` is a function that uses an `'a` to perform a computation that results in a `'b`, then `bind m f` makes `f` depend on the result of `m`.

In the case of `Lwt.bind promise callback`, `callback` depends on the result of `promise`. The code in `callback` cannot run until `promise` is resolved.

When you write

```
let%lwt x = f () in
let%lwt y = g () in
return ()
```

you are really writing `Lwt.bind (f ()) (fun x -> Lwt.bind (g ()) (fun y -> return ()))`. Because `g ()` is inside the callback, it is not run until `f ()` is resolved.

## Applicatives

A functional programming pattern related to the monad is the applicative. An applicative is a generic type `'a t` with a function `map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t`, the function `return : 'a -> 'a t`, and a function `both : 'a t * 'b t -> ('a * 'b) t`. Unlike monads, however, applicatives need not have `bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t`, meaning that with applicatives alone, later computations cannot depend on previous ones. All monads are applicatives, but not all applicatives are monads.

Because `g ()` does not depend on the result of `f ()`, your code can be rewritten to use `both`:

```
let (let*) = bind
let (and*) = both

let* x = f ()
and* y = g () in
return ()
```

This code translates to `bind (fun (x, y) -> return ()) (both (f ()) (g ()))`. `f ()` and `g ()` appear outside the callback to `bind`, meaning that they are run immediately and can await in parallel. `both` combines `f ()` and `g ()` into a single promise.

The `(let*)` and `(and*)` operators are new to OCaml 4.08. If you are using an earlier version of OCaml, you can just write the translation directly.

- [`Lwt.both` in the documentation](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/4.3.0/api/Lwt#VALboth)
- [The Lwt home page contains a code snippit using `let*` and `and*`](https://ocsigen.org/lwt/4.3.0/manual/manual)
- ["Binding operators" (`let*` and `and*`) in the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual046.html)

Answer (score 4):

That particular example runs `f ()` and `g ()` in sequence, i.e. `g ()` doesn't start until after the promise returned by `f ()` is resolved.

The way to see this is, when looking at

```ml
let%lwt x = e in
e'
```

to realize that `e'` becomes the body of a callback, that will run only when `x` is available. So, in the code in the question, Lwt first sees:

```ml
(* Do this first. *)
let%lwt x = f () in

(* Do this once is available. *)
let%lwt y = g () in
return ()
```

and, once `x` is available, it is left with

```ml
(* Do this next. *)
let%lwt y = g () in

(* Do this once y is available. *)
return ()
```

To avoid this serialization, call `f ()` and `g ()` first, without any intervening `let%lwt`, bind variables to the promises `x'`, `y'` these functions return, and wait on the promises:

```ml
let x' = f () in
let y' = g () in
let%lwt x = x' in
let%lwt y = y' in
return ()
```

(And to answer the title, Lwt does not use data dependencies. I don't think a library could have access to this kind of data dependency information).

Comment: Great answer! To add up on data dependency, this would be even harder considering IO.